# execvp() return value if path is wrong

Tags: c, shell, execvp

I am currently writing a custom shell script in C. In order to execute the command, I use the execvp() function. For example:

```
if((execvp(args[0], args)) == -1) //args is a char **array containing the commands arguments
{
    printf("ERROR: Wrong command\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The thing is, when 2 commands are separated by "&&", if the first one is not executed (thus, execvp will return -1) the whole process must break before we go to the next one. It works totally fine, if for example I write " <***some random wrong command***> && ls ".

Although, if I write something like " ls <***some random wrong path***> && ls ", execvp() will be executed normally, and print the message:

> ls: cannot access '...': No such file or directory

Then it will go to the next command. Apparently, in that case execvp() doesn't return -1.

Is there any other value that execvp() returns in that case? If not, how can I check if the path exists before executing the command?

**EDIT**
I just check the value of status (generated by wait(&status) while the parent waits for the child to terminate). If it is non-zero, then it means that the command was not executed.

Comment: What exactly do you have in your `args` array when it fails? The name of a shell script in `args[0]` followed by `NULL`? something like `{ "sh", "-c", "your shell commands", NULL }`?

Comment: Note that the return value of `execvp` (if it returns) is `-1`, not `EXIT_FAILURE`. If it returns, you can check `errno`.

Comment: @Bodo if the command is ls -a && ls -l, then the args will first be { "ls", "-a", NULL } and at the next loop it will be { "ls", "-l", NULL }.

Comment: For a command like `foo && bar`, you need to fork and exec `foo` in the child process, then wait for its exit status before deciding if you need to fork-and-exec `bar`.

Comment: If this is a custom shell program, presumably you call `execvp` from a child process, not from the main shell process? You can add code to the main shell process to wait for the child process to exit and then examine the exit status of the child process to decide how to continue. If the `execvp` function fails in the child process, then the child process should exit with an error so that the main shell process can detect the failure.

Comment: If `ls` reports an error your `execvp` has successfully replaced your program in the current process with the `ls` program, so `execvp` does not return. Your process will terminate with the exit code of `ls`. You can find out the exit code by calling `waitpid` in the parent process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any other value that execvp() returns in that case?

`execvp` doesn't return *any* value in this case, because it succeeded in running the command you asked it to. You couldn't get an error from `ls` unless `ls` had been successfully execed. You probably meant for your `&&` to short-circuit not only on exec failure, but also on a successful exec where the exec'd process returns a nonzero status code (as indicated by `wait` / `waitpid`).

> If not, how can I check if the path exists before executing the command?

Generally speaking, this doesn't make any sense. It's not normal for a shell to make assumptions about how the commands it's running will interpret their arguments, e.g. that one of them should be the name of an existing file. Even if you *did* have such a special case, it would be subject to a race condition (the file exists when the shell checks but not when `ls` runs, or vice versa).

Comment: Until now, I had a wait(&status) at the parent process (execvp() is in the child process) and then I also check "if(WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) == EXIT_FAILURE)" so that it returns EXIT_FAILURE. Is there something else I should have done?

Comment: @ThanosManolis don't check for `== EXIT_FAILURE`, check for *any* nonzero value (in the case of `ls`, it's documented to exit with 2 when a file listed on the commandline doesn't exist. Many programs return different values for different failure conditions. Only 0 represents success.)

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked just checking if status is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

> Although, if I write something like " ls <some random wrong path> &&
>   ls ", execvp() will be executed normally, and print the message:
>
> > ls: cannot access '...': No such file or directory
>
> Then it will go to the next command. Apparently, in that case execvp()
>   doesn't return -1.

The return value of `execvp()` reports on whether a replacement process image was successfully exec'd.  It has nothing to do with the *exit status* of any replacement.  And of course, it only returns at all on failure to replace the current process image with a new one.  This is the only way it *can* work, for the replacement image has to be successfully loaded and launched before its exit status can be determined, and at that point the previous image is no longer available to return *to*.

> Is there any other value that execvp() returns in that case?

No.

> If not,
>   how can I check if the path exists before executing the command?

That's the wrong strategy.  Your shell would need to know how to validate all the operands to every command it could ever execute in order to make that work in the general case.  That's simply impossible for a shell that permits arbitrary programs to be executed.

What you need to do is obtain the first process's *exit status* via `wait` or `waitpid`.  If you're doing this even remotely right, then you are already using one of those to await the first process's termination before launching the second, and, naturally, you cannot determine the exit status until the process actually terminates.  The `wait()` and `waitpid()` functions can each provide an `int` "status" code from which you can extract various information about the process that terminated, including, in the event that it terminated normally, its exit status.